# Infinitely generated non-free group with all proper subgroups free

Tags: gr.group-theory, examples, free-groups

Is there any example of group $G$ satisfying the following properties?

1. $G$ is non-abelian, infinitely generated (i.e. it is not finitely generated) and not a free group.
2. $H< G$ implies that $H$ is a free group.

Clearly such an example should be torsion-free and countable.

---

(Added, from comments) For completeness, here's why it has to be countable. First, it is enough to construct a subgroup of index 2. Indeed, a theorem of Swan asserts that a torsion-free group with a free finite-index subgroup is free. Next, if a group $G$ has no subgroup of index 2 (i.e. every element is product of squares), it is easy to construct a nontrivial countable subgroup $H$ with the same property). In the current setting, $G$ is uncountable so $H$ is a proper subgroup, and hence has to be free, contradiction.

Comment: Olshanskii constructed a non-abelian group all of whose proper subgroups are infinite cyclic and so this group meets your property in a somewhat degenerate way since they are free on one-generator.

Comment: Not sure, but one thing to think about is that if it isn't free, with some given presentation, then there is a word which is nontrivial involving finitely many of the generators. You would probably want to look at the group generated by those generators. The problem though is that those words/generators could generate a lower rank free group (if you where wanting to show it was impossible). That could also give an idea of how one might try to construct an example too.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: The OP wants an infinitely generated group.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg To complement Mark's comment, groups with Olshanskii's property are generated by every non-commuting pair.

Comment: Also why must such groups be countable? I am not seeing it immediately

Comment: @PaulPlummer I don't really understand your first comment. A free group itself has plenty of generating families under which it is not free, so using non-freeness of a given generating family will not help much.

Comment: @PaulPlummer: Locally free but non-free groups are easy to construct. Take a proper ascending HNN extension of the free group $F_k$, and the normal subgroup $N$ generated by $F_k$. For example $\langle a,b,t \mid a^t=ab, b^t=ba>$. The normal closure $N$  of $a,b$ is locally free but not free. The OP does not want this example. He wants all proper subgroups to be free, not just finitely generated subgroups.

Comment: @MarkSapir and YCor Thanks, for some reason my comment sounded like a better idea when typing it, even though I knew of locally free nonfree groups.

Comment: @PaulPlummer: I do not think it is clear (or even true) that these groups must be countable,

Comment: About the countability issue, I think I'm not aware of a non-free group in which every countable subgroup is free. (By analogy, $\mathbf{Z}^\mathbf{N}$ is not free abelian but all its countable subgroups are. Also, the Hawaiian earring group is locally free but has non-free countable subgroups.)

Comment: Sorry.  I missed the infinitely Generated.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.03334.pdf

Comment: $\mathbb Z[\frac12]$

Comment: and this https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/s3-1.1.284

Comment: @BenWieland: $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ is the derived subgroup of the Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(1,2)$, it contains non-free  subgroup $\mathbb{Z}[3/2]$

Comment: @MarkSapir Oh, yeah, but probably better to call the subgroup $3\cdot\mathbb Z[\frac12]$

Comment: @MarkSapir $\mathbf{Z}[3/2]=\mathbf{Z}[1/2]$, so it's not a proper subgroup. Actually, the only unital subrings of $\mathbf{Z}[1/2]$ are itself and $\mathbf{Z}$. Also, every subgroup of $\mathbf{Z}[1/2]$ is $\{0\}$, infinite cyclic, or has finite index and isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}[1/2]$ (namely equals $k\mathbf{Z}[1/2]$ for some unique positive odd $k$.)

Comment: @BenWieland a torsion-free abelian group in which every proper subgroup is cyclic, is itself cyclic, by an easy argument.

Comment: I should have been more clear, I meant free non-abelian.

Comment: It feels as though no such group exists. Since every finitely-generated subgroup is both proper and free by assumption, how could the group have any nontrivial relations?

Comment: @SantanaAfton -- see Mark Sapir's comment above.

Comment: @HJRW Are you referring to the HNN construction? In that example, if you take the relation $a^t=ab$ and the group generated by all letters involved, you don’t get a proper subgroup. This never happens in OP’s situation.

Comment: @SantanaAfton Every finitely generated group of the rationals/Hawaiian earring is free but these are not free

Comment: @W4cc0 no, you don't: there are always free abelian subgroups. So the question was correctly stated, and wouldn't if "non-abelian" were added. Also as already mentioned, every group with your property has a non-abelian free subgroup.

Comment: @SantanaAfton It's overly simplistic, if not senseless, to think of a free group as a group with no relations.

Comment: Higman constructed non-free groups of cardinality $\aleph_1$ in which every countable subgroup is free.  But every proper subgroup being free sounds hard.

Comment: @YCor, I meant $G$ non-abelian (even if it makes sense in this case, it is easy to see that there are no abelian such groups), of course it would have no sense in the other case; but unfortunately I always write the opposite of what I would like to, sorry.

Comment: @W4cc0 on the other hand do you maintain your claim that such a group has to be countable? or do you want to require the group to be countable? (I guess the countable case and uncountable case are quite distinct questions.)

Comment: @SantanaAfton -- Mark explained how to construct a non-free group in which every finitely generated subgroup is free. This contradicts your intuition that since "every finitely-generated subgroup is both proper and free" ... the group must itself be free.

Comment: @YCor such a group must be countable because if it is not, then it would be residually finite, but then a very well known theorem of Swan would imply that it is free

Comment: @W4cc0 thanks; I wouldn't have said "clearly"! I didn't know Swan's theorem, what does it say exactly? Here's an argument to show residual finiteness: it's enough to check that there is a proper subgroup of index 2. Indeed, the latter being free by assumption, it has to be res. finite and hence so is the whole group. Now, if by contradiction there is no subgroup of index 2, then every element is a finite product of squares. From this, it is easy to construct a nontrivial countable subgroup in which every element is a finite product of squares, and hence this is a non-free countable subgroup.

Comment: @YCor You're probably right I should not have have said "clearly" but in my mind it was a very direct application of some known facts (to me at least) in infinite group theory. Swan Theorem says that if your group is torsion-free and it is a finite extension of a free group, then it must be free itself.

Comment: Since a partly equivalent question [was just asked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375090/converse-of-schreier-theorem), I have added the short argument to discard the uncountable case.